# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 - PHP, MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting some data through PHP in MySql database, but unfortunately i am getting this error:

`Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

From the following code:

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
include_once('dbconn.php');
$profile_created_by = $_POST['profile_created_by'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$dd = $_POST['dd'];
$mm = $_POST['mm'];
$yyyy = $_POST['yyyy'];
$dob = $dd.'-'.$mm.'-'.$yyyy;
$marital_status = $_POST['marital_status'];
$religion = $_POST['religion'];
$mother_tongue = $_POST['mother_tongue'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$sql="INSERT INTO user VALUES ('$profile_created_by', '$name', '$gender', '$dob', '$marital_status', '$religion', '$mother_tongue', '$country', '$mobile', '$email', '$password')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$conn))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully";
mysql_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Can anybody help me out with this error?

Comment: match your database column and values you are inserting

Comment: count ('$profile_created_by', '$name', '$gender', '$dob', '$marital_status', '$religion', '$mother_tongue', '$country', '$mobile', '$email', '$password') and number of column in your table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more columns in user table which are not mentioned here (e.g ID), You have to specify which data is for which column.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO user (profile_created_by,name,gender,dob,marital_status,religion,mother_tongue,country,mobile,email,password) VALUES ('$profile_created_by', '$name', '$gender', '$dob', '$marital_status', '$religion', '$mother_tongue', '$country', '$mobile', '$email', '$password')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error bcoz number of columns in the table `user` doesn't match with number of values supplied. So try using this type of format:

```
INSERT INTO user(columnNames,...) 
VALUES(respective_values,....);
```